# Reading invalid data from X: The readable size is Y bytes, but Z bytes may be read

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, gdi+

I updated my `Visual Studio 2019` to version `16.1.3` and I'm now getting a warning inside a `GDI+` library based function to get the encoder:

```
inline int get_encoder(const WCHAR* format, CLSID* p_clsid)
{
    UINT image_encoders_count = 0;
    UINT image_encoder_array_size = 0;

    GetImageEncodersSize(&image_encoders_count, &image_encoder_array_size);
    if (image_encoder_array_size == 0)
    {
        return -1; // Failure
    }

    const auto p_image_codec_info = static_cast<ImageCodecInfo*>(malloc(image_encoder_array_size));
    if (p_image_codec_info == nullptr)
    {
        return -1; // Failure
    }

    GetImageEncoders(image_encoders_count, image_encoder_array_size, p_image_codec_info);

    for (UINT image_encoder_index = 0; image_encoder_index < image_encoders_count; image_encoder_index++)
    {
        // TODO: Fix the warning "Reading invalid data from 'p_image_codec_info':  the readable size is 'image_encoder_array_size' bytes, but '208' bytes may be read."
        const auto image_codec_info = p_image_codec_info[image_encoder_index];
        const auto mime_type = image_codec_info.MimeType;
        const auto comparison_result = wcscmp(mime_type, format);
        if (comparison_result == 0)
        {
            *p_clsid = image_codec_info.Clsid;
            free(p_image_codec_info);
            return image_encoder_index; // Success
        }
    }

    free(p_image_codec_info);
    return -1; // Failure
}
```

`Visual Studio` yields the following warning:

```
Reading invalid data from 'p_image_codec_info':  the readable size is 'image_encoder_array_size' bytes, but '208' bytes may be read.
```

[image]

The code works but how can this warning be fixed? I debugged the code step-by-step but I do not see an issue with the indexing or the allocated size of `p_image_codec_info`. The documentation for the warning is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/c6385).

Comment: It's a false alert from the static analyzer, which can't understand the relations between `image_encoders_count` and `image_encoder_array_size`. Try to add `assert(image_encoders_count * sizeof(ImageCodecInfo) <= image_encoder_array_size);` or `assert(image_encoders_count <= image_encoder_array_size / sizeof(ImageCodecInfo));` before the loop.

Comment: Also try `__analysis_assume()` instead of `assert`.

Comment: @Evg: Neither suggestion fixed the warning. Maybe I can rewrite the code to make the static analyzer understand the relation?

Comment: I don't have VS installed, so I can't experiment myself. Try to use `image_encoder_array_size / sizeof(ImageCodecInfo)` as an upper bound (though I don't like this possible solution). You can also use `#pragma warning(suppress : 6385)`, and in the present case this is probably the best option.

Comment: Even the suppression pragma does not seem to work...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As commented by [`Evg`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1625187/evg), this seems to be a [`Visual Studio`](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com)/[`Resharper C++`](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper-cpp) static analyzer bug since the code is correct.